# Combine tables based on fixed rank

Tags: sql, union, presto, rank

Say that I have one table ("OldTable") with a continuous rank of items, thas was calculated in advance, starting from 1 up to some number.
I have a new table ("NewTable") with some non-continuous, not starting from 0, ranking (e.g. values of 3 and 5). No item has duplicates and does not exist in the other table.

I wish to combine both of them into one table, while keeping the NewTable items in their fixed position, and adjusting the rank of the old table accordingly.

For example

```
OldTable
+------+------+
| item | rank |
+------+------+
| o1   |    1 |
| o2   |    2 |
| o3   |    3 |
| o4   |    4 |
| o5   |    5 |
+------+------+

NewTable
+------+------+
| item | rank |
+------+------+
| n1   |    3 |
| n2   |    5 |
+------+------+

Output Table
+------+------+
| item | rank |
+------+------+
| o1   |    1 |
| o2   |    2 |
| n1   |    3 |
| o3   |    4 |
| n2   |    5 |
| o4   |    6 |
| o5   |    7 |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

1. Create a sequence table
2. Join new table on this sequence tables, this ensures the correct fixed position
3. "Recount" the empty rows
4. Join the old table on this new column

The following query should give the desired result:

```
with old_values as
(
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('o1', 1),
            ('o2', 2),
            ('o3', 3),
            ('o4', 4),
            ('o5', 5)
    ) AS t (id, rnk)
)
,new_values as
(
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('n1', 3),
            ('n2', 5)
    ) AS t (id, rnk)
)
,total_ranks as
(
    select x from unnest(sequence(1,7)) t(x) 
)
,fixed_new_rank as
(
    select *
    ,case when nv.rnk is null then tr.x-COUNT(nv.rnk)OVER(order by tr.x) else null end empty_rnk
    from total_ranks tr
    left join new_values nv
        on tr.x = nv.rnk
)
select fnr.x,coalesce(fnr.id,ov.id) id
from fixed_new_rank fnr
left join old_values ov
    on fnr.empty_rnk = ov.rnk
order by x;
```